# Should I ever use query hints?

Tags: sql-server, tuning, microsoft-dynamics

SQL Server 2008 R2, Dynamics AX 2009
We have this ugly query

```
DECLARE @P1 NVARCHAR(5), @P2 INT, @P3 INT, @P4 NVARCHAR(11), @P5 INT, @P6 NVARCHAR(5), @P7 NVARCHAR(11)SELECT A.SALESID,
   A.LINENUM,
   A.ITEMID,
   A.SALESSTATUS,
   A.LEDGERACCOUNT,
   A.NAME,
   A.EXTERNALITEMID,
   A.TAXGROUP,
   A.QTYORDERED,
   A.SALESDELIVERNOW,
   A.REMAINSALESPHYSICAL,
   A.REMAINSALESFINANCIAL,
   A.COSTPRICE,
   A.SALESPRICE,
   A.CURRENCYCODE,
   A.LINEPERCENT,
   A.LINEDISC,
   A.LINEAMOUNT,
   A.CONFIRMEDDLV,
   A.RESERVATION,
   A.SALESUNIT,
   A.DIMENSION,
   A.DIMENSION2_,
   A.DIMENSION3_,
   A.PRICEUNIT,
   A.PROJTRANSID,
   A.INVENTTRANSID,
   A.CUSTGROUP,
   A.CUSTACCOUNT,
   A.SALESQTY,
   A.SALESMARKUP,
   A.INVENTDELIVERNOW,
   A.MULTILNDISC,
   A.MULTILNPERCENT,
   A.SALESTYPE,
   A.BLOCKED,
   A.COMPLETE,
   A.REMAININVENTPHYSICAL,
   A.TRANSACTIONCODE,
   A.TAXITEMGROUP,
   A.TAXAUTOGENERATED,
   A.UNDERDELIVERYPCT,
   A.OVERDELIVERYPCT,
   A.BARCODE,
   A.BARCODETYPE,
   A.INVENTREFTRANSID,
   A.INVENTREFTYPE,
   A.INVENTREFID,
   A.ITEMBOMID,
   A.LINEHEADER,
   A.SCRAP,
   A.DLVMODE,
   A.INVENTTRANSIDRETURN,
   A.PROJCATEGORYID,
   A.PROJID,
   A.INVENTDIMID,
   A.TRANSPORT,
   A.STATPROCID,
   A.PORT,
   A.PROJLINEPROPERTYID,
   A.RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED,
   A.CUSTOMERLINENUM,
   A.REMAININVENTFINANCIAL,
   A.DELIVERYADDRESS,
   A.DELIVERYNAME,
   A.DELIVERYSTREET,
   A.DELIVERYZIPCODE,
   A.DELIVERYCITY,
   A.DELIVERYCOUNTY,
   A.DELIVERYSTATE,
   A.DELIVERYCOUNTRYREGIONID,
   A.DELIVERYTYPE,
   A.CUSTOMERREF,
   A.PURCHORDERFORMNUM,
   A.RECEIPTDATECONFIRMED,
   A.BLANKETREFTRANSID,
   A.STATTRIANGULARDEAL,
   A.SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED,
   A.SHIPPINGDATECONFIRMED,
   A.ADDRESSREFRECID,
   A.ADDRESSREFTABLEID,
   A.EINVOICEACCOUNTCODE,
   A.DELIVERYDATECONTROLTYPE,
   A.ATPINCLPLANNEDORDERS,
   A.ATPTIMEFENCE,
   A.ACTIVITYNUMBER,
   A.RETURNALLOWRESERVATION,
   A.ITEMREPLACED,
   A.RETURNDEADLINE,
   A.EXPECTEDRETQTY,
   A.RETURNSTATUS,
   A.RETURNARRIVALDATE,
   A.RETURNCLOSEDDATE,
   A.RETURNDISPOSITIONCODEID,
   A.CUSTOMSNAME_MX,
   A.CUSTOMSDOCNUMBER_MX,
   A.CUSTOMSDOCDATE_MX,
   A.PROPERTYNUMBER_MX,
   A.REFRETURNINVOICETRANS_W,
   A.POSTINGPROFILE_RU,
   A.PRICEAGREEMENTDATE_RU,
   A.CORRECTIONDESC_PL,
   A.CREDITNOTEINTERNALREF_PL,
   A.DELIVERYFLAT_RU,
   A.DELIVERYBUILDING_RU,
   A.DELIVERYESTATE_RU,
   A.DELIVERYSTREETID_RU,
   A.DELIVERYSETTLEMENTID_RU,
   A.DELIVERYTOWNID_RU,
   A.RBOVARIANTID,
   A.HHTHANDHELDUSERID,
   A.HHTTRANSTIME,
   A.HHTTRANSDATE,
   A.ECC_PRICEGROUPID,
   A.ECC_SALESPRICECALC,
   A.ECC_CHEQUENUMBER,
   A.ECC_CHEQUEROWNUMBER,
   A.ECC_DOCUMENTCOMMENT,
   A.ECC_SHOPASSISTANT,
   A.ECC_SALEDATEFROMCOMISS,
   A.ECC_CARDNUMBER,
   A.ECC_ISPRESENTS,
   A.ECC_ISHOPSALESID,
   A.ECC_ISHOPPOSTPACKAGENUMBER,
   A.ECC_ISHOPINVENTTRANSFERCREATED,
   A.ECC_ISHOPINVENTTRANSFERLI50013,
   A.ECC_DISTRIBUTIONRATING,
   A.ECC_CASHNUMBER,
   A.ECC_ISHOPRRN,
   A.ECC_ISHOPSHIPPINGINVENTLO50017,
   A.ECC_ISHOPINVENTTRANSFERRE50018,
   A.ECC_ISHOPSALESLINESALECREATED,
   A.ECC_ISHOPINTEGRATIONPAYMETHOD,
   A.ECC_ISHOPPROCESSQTY,
   A.ECC_ISHOPFINISHED,
   A.ECC_RBOLOYALTYNUMBERCARD,
   A.ECC_ISHOPBONUSESPOINTS,
   A.ECC_ISHOPRATINGSPOINTS,
   A.ECC_RBOLOYALTYPOINTSACCUM50026,
   A.ECC_ISHOPTRANSDATETIME,
   A.ECC_ISHOPTRANSDATETIMETZID,
   A.ECC_ISHOPEXTRAPOINTSPAY,
   A.ECC_ISHOPBONUSESPOINTSPAY,
   A.ECC_ISHOPPICKUPINVENTLOCA50030,
   A.ECC_ISHOPSALESRESERVE,
   A.ECC_RBONETAMOUNT,
   A.ECC_RBOTAXAMOUNT,
   A.MODIFIEDDATETIME,
   A.CREATEDDATETIME,
   A.RECVERSION,
   A.RECID,
   B.INVENTCOLORID,
   B.INVENTSIZEID,
   B.INVENTLOCATIONID,
   B.ECC_BUSINESSUNITID,
   B.ECC_SEASONID,
   B.INVENTDIMID,
   B.RECVERSION,
   101090 FROM SALESLINE A,
 INVENTDIM B WHERE((A.DATAAREAID = @P1)
  AND ((((A.COMPLETE = @P2)
         AND (A.ECC_ISHOPSALESRESERVE = @P3))
        AND NOT((A.ECC_ISHOPSALESID = @P4)))
       AND (A.ECC_ISHOPFINISHED = @P5)))
 AND ((B.DATAAREAID = @P6)
      AND ((B.INVENTLOCATIONID = @P7)
           AND (A.INVENTDIMID = B.INVENTDIMID))) ORDER BY A.DATAAREAID DESC,
     A.INVENTDIMID DESC OPTION(FAST 1, LOOP JOIN, FORCE ORDER);
```

I think the query options that are used here are not what we actually should do with this specific query to try to make it faster. It goes very slow on our system. The plan is here:
[QUERY PLAN](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1vUlIasx)
Will appreciate any help

Comment: Whether or not you should ever use query hints isn't really pertinent here. You posted a query from a 3rd party vendor tool from a version that's ~8 years old with no other information (hardware, indexes, etc.). It could be much more than the hints making your query slow (and you never did define 'slow'). You also didn't show us how it runs without the query hints. Have you tried that to test your hypothesis? Bringing up the rear, the plan XML you pasted shows a cursor performing an insert with an estimated 171.6 million rows. That's gonna be slow just about anywhere.

Comment: And just throwing it out there since this is Dynamics, have you raised a support ticket with them to address performance concerns around the query hint they wrote in?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I'm fairly sure this particular query hint is added by a customization either by a partner or the customer.

Comment: @TomV Could be. That's why I upvoted your answer when I saw it. Though it might not be, because I've seen Dynamics queries littered with all manner of nonsense out of the box.

Comment: @TomV IIRC I've seen lots of OPTIMIZE FOR stuff as well. But the comments here probably aren't a great place to carry on like this :) Drop me an email if you'd like!

Answer (score 12):

First of all, the plan you pasted doesn't exactly match the query you posted, because AX uses API_CURSOR behind the scenes.

Apart from that, this is a custom query one of your (or a vendor) developers wrote. (all the ECC_* fields are non-standard) and all those hints are explicitly added by that developer.

The 3 options you see

- `FAST 1`
- `LOOP JOIN`
- `FORCE ORDER`

Are added in the code for the customization using these keywords

- `firstFast`
- `forceNestedLoop`
- `forceSelectOrder`

See the [Select Statement Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656402.aspx).

What I suggest you do is talk to your developer and ask him why he has added all those hints in code.

Since all those fields added to the `SALESLINE` table are added by a customization, make sure they are properly indexed, and then try removing all the nonsense keywords.